# Modern UI app pinned to second screen

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

In a previous question I asked [if Metro can span over two monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors), but seems not to be the case and it opens always on my primary monitor.

Now I pinned a Modern UI Application (Mail) to the side of my second monitor. Now I really have two problems:

1. When I press the WIN keyboard, Modern UI opens on the second screen (so far always on the first), but
2. When I go to the bottom left corner (where the start-button used to be), the Modern UI opens again on the first screen and my Mail Application pinned to the other screen is being changed to the first screen! (so pinning over multiple monitors doesn't work)

Well the Feature of pinning Applications to the side is cool, but does it really not work with two / multiple monitors?

Comment: Seems there is room for improvement here at Microsoft, can't get that they still can't get it right after having made multiple things multi-monitor, this once again confirms their focus on tablets...

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 Enterprise! I think this Windows should not be focused for tablets - exaclty here should Microsoft make a real difference between Home and Enterprise!

Comment: The `Start Screen` is only displayed on a single monitor.  This has nothing to do with `Home` ( no idea what you mean by this ) and `Enterprise` in this regard.

Comment: With 'Home' I mean the non-Pro, non-Enterprise, non-RT basic Windows 8 (Unfortunately this has not a specific name).

Comment: I wasn't kidding on the other question when I said "if you launch an app on one monitor and then go to bring up the Start Screen on your other - it closes the app that was up on the first monitor".  It's *terrible*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At current, Multi-monitor support for metro apps is iffy at best. Metro apps can only be open and drawn onto one monitor at a time, so your pinned app will move along with it just as you are experiencing.

This is a very vocal topic flying though the MSDN feature request lines so I would assume this is a feature to be added in the future once an acceptable solution is found.

Until then, My workaround is that I have set up one of my three monitors to be my "Metro screen" and that is the one which i manipulate metro applications.

I, for one, cant wait till i can put metro apps all over my screen real estate.