# windows 8 dual screen setting

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI with Dual / Multiple Monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors)

it's possible where primary screen always showing metro UI and 2nd screen use ad the display  screen? so if i press icon (example "outlook" icon) and the 2nd display show the Outlook windows instead close the metro ui in primary display.

Answer (score 0):

Without any kind of addon/utility, this would not be possible with a stock Windows 8. However, you can use Windows Key + Page Up/Down to move Metro to your other monitor. However, the Metro App would follow.