# Is the Windows8/10 start screen capable of spanning 2 monitors?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Is the Windows8 start screen capable of spanning 2 monitors?  This is not a question of multiple monitor support; this is a question of whether the Windows-8 start screen is able to display across 2 monitors, not as a mirrored display but as a additive display to the width of the single screen start screen.   Or, does a app exist that I can purchase for it to do this?

Comment: try this tool: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1104241-windows-8-start-menu-modifier/ If it doesn't support it, ask the creator of the tool if it is possible to add.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI with Dual / Multiple Monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. Windows 8 new UI only runs on the primary display. You cannot make it "expand" to additional monitors.