# Is there any way to make the Windows 8.1 start screen span multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, start-screen

I've done a search and come up with nothing other than a couple of posts from a year or two back when it didn't appear to be possible.  Does anyone know of an aftermarket utility that will perform this task now?

Thanks

Comment: If its possible.  Its not possible without third-party software.  I am not personally aware of any third-party software that does this, there isn't a  huge demand for it.

Comment: That's a shame.  There must be some programmatical difficulty at a low level in windows I assume, or I'm sure someone would have made it work by now.  I think most people who use 8.1 on a multiple monitor setup would benefit and prefer it once they had tried it.

Comment: Most people want to disable the Start Screen that is where most of the effort has gone.  Furthermore, no version of windows, has supported the start menu/start screen to appear on multiple windows.  You can switch the monitor the start screen is on with a simple keyboard shortcut though unlike the start menu.

Comment: And when I first got 8.1 (having skipped straight from Vista) I was the same.  But now that I've used it a month or two I'm more ok with it.  Dual monitor support could allow you to have the tiles on one screen and the "Apps" list on the other screen, for example.

Comment: I don't disagree.  The problem is we are the minority.  Windows 10 will be changing things.  Most Windows 8.x and even Windows 10 devices will be touch device, which have a single monitor (touch) most of the time, and only have more if its placed in a docking station.

Comment: Out of curiosity would you want the start screen to be spanned or cloned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Windows8 start screen capable of spanning 2 monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/526128/is-the-windows8-start-screen-capable-of-spanning-2-monitors)

Comment: Spanned Eric.  Cloning would be much easier programatically I'm sure, but of much less interest.

Comment: Better duplicate: [Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI with Dual / Multiple Monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors)

Comment: If you want it just spanned.   There is a solution, using AMD's Eyefinity, is likely the best solution.  This will make multiple monitors a single display instead of the default behavior of each being separate.  There are third-party solutions that do this that are not specific to `Nvidia` or `AMD` GPUs.

Comment: That will drastically affect everything else about Windows and individuals windows' behaviour though.  Definitely do not want.

Comment: But it does feel like it SHOULD be possible for a third party app to trick Windows into seeing one large display for the start screen, and then to split the resultant image up onto the separate monitors.  Someone code this please :)